# True or False $Re f(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Make an examples $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ holomorph (If it exists) with the property:(Justify your answer)

$Re f(z)>0$ for all $z\in\Bbb{C}$ and $f$ is not constant.

**My attemp:** I find a question in Conway that is discussed in 
[$f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ analytic. Show $\operatorname{Re}(f(z)) \geq 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621745/f-d-rightarrow-mathbbc-analytic-show-operatornamerefz-geq-0)

But my question is difference. Because we have not the hypothesis   $Re f(z)\geq 0$ and the domain is $\Bbb{C}$ instead of $D$. 
So we can not use the open mapping theorem and I think there is not such function!

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229312/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such $f$ exists. Suppose a non constant function $f(z)$ and let $f(z)=u+iv$ and consider the function $F(z)=e^{-f(z)}$. Then, $$|F(z)|=|e^{-u-iv}|=e^{-u}$$ Note that since $\Re f(z)= u>0$, it follows that $|F(z)|<1$ and by Liouville's Theorem $F(z)$ is constant.
This implies that $F'(z)=-f'(z)e^{-f(z)}=0$ and this further implies that $f'(z)=0$. Hence, $f(z)$ must be a constant.